# In which class/file of Elementor form processing should post-processing handler code live, so it will not get overwritten during plugin updates?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor, spam-prevention

I have a written a post-UI pre-process form data filter (in PHP8.1), which receives Elementor-Pro submitted form records, and decides which ones to delete.

It is currently installed inside: /httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/forms/classes/ajax-handler.php, which is a bad idea, since it will be overwritten on next plugin update (Elementor-pro).

Is there a wordpress/elementor hook that can be registered, which runs as form-submission pre-processor, which can be run from the child-theme's functions.php ?

If not, In which class/method/function will be the optimal location for that logic, keeping in mind:

function must be run AFTER user successful submission
function must be run BEFORE server emails the results to admin
No negative feedback should be shown to the user

For admins:

The focus of the question is the specific location and entry point for a post-processing PHP code (function), ininside Elementor-pro plugin domain, which is inside a Wordpress installation, which runs after code submission and before elementor is sending the records submitted by the user to 1. the db, 2. to the email recipients.
If you have written code for wordpress plugins (specifically elementor) you'd understand the focus of this question.